# Pandas send multiple DataFrames to_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have three symbols with price data and successfully imported/modified that price data as shown below:

```
def read_files(): 
    assets = ['ES','ZN','VX']
    path = r"C:\Users\cost9\OneDrive\Documents\PYTHON\Exported_Data\%s\*.csv"

    files = []
    for a in assets:
        files.extend(glob.iglob(path % a))

    df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]

    for b in df_list:
        b['Returns'] = b['Close'].pct_change()
```

The sample data now looks like this after creating the 'Returns' column above:

```
Ticker  Date/Time   Close   Returns
ES U7   3/14/2017 5:29  2365.5  
ES U7   3/14/2017 6:29  2362.25 -0.001373917
ES U7   3/14/2017 8:29  2355    -0.003069108
ES U7   3/14/2017 9:29  2359.25 0.001804671
ES U7   3/14/2017 10:29 2356    -0.001377556
ES U7   3/14/2017 11:29 2358    0.000848896
ES U7   3/14/2017 12:29 2358.5  0.000212044
ES U7   3/14/2017 13:29 2360.25 0.000741997
ES U7   3/14/2017 14:29 2360.5  0.000105921
ES U7   3/14/2017 21:29 2361.5  0.000423639
ES U7   3/14/2017 22:29 2363.5  0.000846919
ES U7   3/14/2017 23:29 2363.75 0.000105775
ES U7   3/15/2017 0:29  2364.5  0.000317292
ES U7   3/15/2017 1:29  2363.5  -0.000422922
```

Each of the three symbols' CSV files would look like this. Now I want to move each of these three DataFrames into separate folders:

```
end_path_to_csv = "C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\%s\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\blah.csv" 

for c in df_list:
    c.to_csv(path_or_buf = end_path_to_csv % assets)
```

I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\['ES', 'ZN', 'VX']\\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\blah.csv"
```

Unfortunately I can't convert the 'assets' and 'df_list' (Dataframe) values into a dictionary - if I do that then the DataFrames won't be called and there's no csv data available.

I have three folders, each the exact same except for the symbol in the file directory, for example:

```
"C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\ES\\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\blah.csv"
```

This would be for the 'ES' symbol, the 'VX' would replace 'ES' if I was referring to that DataFrame and so on.

How can I save each dataframe into the corresponding folder?

Comment: is this a folder on your computer? C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\['ES', 'ZN', 'VX']\\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\

Comment: @PaulH no, but each of the three folders is present as follows: C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\ES\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\

Comment: You made the same error from your last question I told you not to,

Comment: You need to iterate over `assets`, rather than insert `assets` into a string.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ understood, the issue is 'a' isn't defined in the for loop being referenced, and I'm not sure how to define 'a' for 'assets' in the loop without creating a dictionary without eliminating the dataframe quality of 'df_list'.

Comment: See my answer below. vvvv

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ thanks again, that works great!

Comment: @ColeStarbuck Unaccepted?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ  I have an issue with my prior code...df_list isn't creating 3 separate dataframes. However your answer works great so I appreciate the help and have accepted!

Comment: Hmm, it isn't? Is it throwing errors? Please try debugging it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I can't post a question for another 90 minutes but even though all three files are getting sent successfully to their locations per your loop, the three csv files are all showing data for ES, rather than ES, ZN and VX respectively. So no errors, just the data isn't coming out correct when I create/modify the dataframes.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code and examine your `df_list` contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `zip` `assets` and `df_list` together and iterate over them.

```
assets = ['ES','ZN','VX']
dst_path = ...

for p, c in zip(assets, df_list):
    c.to_csv(dst_path % p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over df_list, yet the path is the same in every loop-iteration.Try this:

```
end_path_to_csv = "C:\\Users\\cost9\\OneDrive\\Documents\\PYTHON\\Daily Tasks\\Individual Trading\\%s\CSV\\15M\\Trend_Identifier\\blah.csv" 

for idx, c in enumerate(df_list):
    c.to_csv(path_or_buf = end_path_to_csv % assets[idx])
```

Comment: Why enumerate indices when you could just zip `assets` with `df_list`?

Comment: `df_list` is initially created from looping over `assets` (they have the same length), that was what led me to use enumerate @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ